# Is Ubuntu stable based on Debian unstable?

Tags: debian, ubuntu

When I go to [ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com) today (04/30/2023) it offers me to download `22.04.2 LTS` or `23.04`. I assume both are considered "stable".

According to [this mapping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445487/what-debian-version-are-the-different-ubuntu-versions-based-on) Ubuntu `22.04` is based on Debian bookworm (Debian 12) which I think is currently [unstable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history) as Debian bullseye (Debian 11) is current stable. Ubuntu `23.04` must be based on something even newer.

How can that be?

Update:
I launched Ubuntu `22.04.2 LTS` and this is the output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

And this is `/etc/debian_version`:

```
bookworm/sid
```

Comment: Ubuntu does what ubuntu does - not sure how 22.04 is based on bookworm, clearly the kernel version isn't - by the way, bookworm isn't *unstable*, it is Debian *testing* ... `sid` is (and always will be) *unstable*

Comment: @JaromandaX Current Ubuntu LTS is indeed based on sid (see my update).

Comment: [This link may be helpful](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Merging).

Comment: @zomega that doesn’t mean anything, testing versions of Debian always identify themselves as codename/sid; sid is dropped from `/etc/debian_version` when the corresponding version of Debian is released. But Ubuntu does track sid, not a specific version of Debian.

Comment: `Current Ubuntu LTS is indeed based on sid` - you said bookworm was *unstable* - but thanks for incorrecting me

Answer (score 0):

The `sid` realease is not really a version. It is just a stream of the newest packages. Then your Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS is based on a snapshot of the `sid`. The Ubuntu 22.10 is based on a newer snapshot of the `sid`, then is newer whatever what you can read on a mapping table.